# ASP.net how to use sessions?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I need to assign my variable to session. I tried this:

```
string name = string.Empty
Session["N"] = name;
```

and it won't work.

```
Error   1   Invalid token '[' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Error   2   Invalid token '"N"' in class, struct, or interface member declaration   
Error   3   Identifier expected
```

Where I'm wrong?

I'm using ASP.net in Visual Studio 2008.

Error   1   Invalid token '[' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Error   2   Invalid token '"N"' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
Error   3   Identifier expected

Comment: Why won't it work? What happens? Do you get any errors?

Comment: "it won't work" isn't helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "and it won't work"?

Comment: I got ["N"] underlined with message: "Identifier expected"

Comment: I updated question with errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

missing `;` end of  first line.

```
string name = string.Empty;
Session["N"] = name;
string test= Session["N"].ToString();//Catch Your session
```

Comment: ; lost during copying.
I got ["N"] underlined with message: "Identifier expected".

Comment: Put your code inside `Page_Load` and check its work or not?its work perfectly D:) .

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with that code (except a missing semicolon, as Shree Khanal pointed out, but that can't be the issue, right?).

As long as the code is in the page class, the `Session` property is available. If you have the code in a different class, you don't have the `Session` property available, then you need to get it from the current context:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["N"] = name;
```

When reading the value from the session collection, the type is `Object`, not `String`, so you need to cast it:

```
string name = Session["N"] as string;
```

Using the `as` keyword means that you can attempt to read the value even if it would not exist, or if it happens to be set to a different data type. In that case you will get a `null` reference back.